# Resgatar índices dos elementos do meu data.frame

Tags: r, matriz, data.frame

Tenho um data.frame que é  filtrado de outro data.frame. (segue imagem abaixo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, gostaria de filtrar novamente esse data.frame e recuperar num vetor seus respectivos índices originais.

Exemplo: Digamos que filtrei e o resultado foram os itens `1(Jardim), 11(apiário) e 28(museu)`

Eu quero um vetor `V[1,11,28]`, ou seja, com os índices originais.

O que tentei fazer só me retornou os índices sequenciais.
exemplo `[1,2,3,4,5,6...,11]`.

Outro Exemplo:

No meu data.frame tenho uma coluna com o seguinte vetor -> 16.2 0.4 21.0 18.8 0.8 0.8 18.1 1.5 21.1 21.0 1.9

Realizei um filtro para mostrar as linhas do meu data.frama que estivessem na coluna mencionada acima valores menores ou iguais a 5.

depois o filtro a coluna mencionada acima ficou assim: 0.4 0.8 0.8 1.5 1.9

depois do filtro meu data.frame ficou como mostrado na figura abaixo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem, quero recuperar os índices das linhas correspondentes as informações do filtro num vetor, seguindo o exemplo, minha resposta final seria v = [3,12,13,16,40]

Alguma ajuda ou dica de como fazer isso??

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(42)
```

Suponha você tenha o seguinte `data.frame`:

```
let = rep(letters[1:5], 3)
valor = rnorm(length(let))
dat = data.frame(let, valor)

#   let       valor
# 1    a  1.37095845
# 2    b -0.56469817
# 3    c  0.36312841
# 4    d  0.63286260
# 5    e  0.40426832
# 6    a -0.10612452
# 7    b  1.51152200
# 8    c -0.09465904
# 9    d  2.01842371
# 10   e -0.06271410
# 11   a  1.30486965
# 12   b  2.28664539
# 13   c -1.38886070
# 14   d -0.27878877
# 15   e -0.13332134
```

Agora você filtra somente as letras `a`:

```
dat2 = dat[which(dat$let == "a"), ]

#     let      valor
# 1    a  1.3709584
# 6    a -0.1061245
# 11   a  1.3048697
```

Para encontrar os índices de `a` do data frame original:

```
v = which(dat$let == dat2$let)

# [1]  1  6 11
```

Comment: No meu caso só tenho essa mensagem de erro " longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Comment: vetor original: 16.2  0.4 21.0 18.8  0.8  0.8 18.1  1.5 21.1 21.0  1.9

Comment: vetor filtro: 0.4 0.8 0.8 1.5 1.9

Comment: Fiz o mesmo procedimento, comparando o original com o filtrado para obter os indices

Comment: Meu filtro no caso esta sendo menores ou iguais a 5 (no meu código esse valor sera dinâmico)

Comment: No caso esses vetores sao colunas do meu data.frame

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta com esta tentativa?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Uma sugestão é você:

1 - criar uma coluna chamada "id" com o número da linha de cada observação,

2 - aplicar o filtro desejado;

3 - extrair o vetor desejado com a função `pull()`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
df <- tibble(valor = c(16.2, 0.4, 21.0, 18.8, 0.8, 0.8, 18.1, 1.5, 21.1, 21.0, 1.9))

# A tibble: 11 × 1
   valor
   <dbl>
 1  16.2
 2   0.4
 3  21  
 4  18.8
 5   0.8
 6   0.8
 7  18.1
 8   1.5
 9  21.1
10  21  
11   1.9
```

- Com a função `mutate()` crio uma coluna `id` que será preenchida com o número da linha (`row_number()`);
- depois uso `select()` apenas para ordenar as colunas;
- em seguida, uso a função `filter()` para filtrar os valores `<= 5`
- e, por fim, o `pull()` para extrair a coluna desejada na forma de um vetor.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  select(id, valor) %>% 
  filter(valor <= 5) %>% 
  pull(id)
```

resultado:

```
[1]  2  5  6  8 11
```